# Firestore data filter by date android java

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I created an android application that shows me my firestore database that I created but my problem is that I want to show the data by date in a specific way.

For example: for *today (26-12-2021)* when I open the app I want to see ***ONLY*** the data created today in an activity.

And I want to show the old data *(25-12-2021) and before that* in another activity.

I looked over some solutions but didn't find exactly what I wanted,
any help would be effective for me. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Can you share any code you have created so far and the structure of the data you are looking at? I would think you would just return x activity where the date equals today and y activity where the date is before today?

Comment: "I looked over some solutions but didn't find exactly what I wanted" Since filtering on date has been covered multiple times already, without seeing what you already did this question is likely going to be closed as a duplicate of one of the top answers from https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D%5Bandroid%5D+date+query

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that your data is in the Firestore database, you must be able to render data via queries. If your document has a field "created_on" which is the date field, then you can filter using it. You can do something like this:

```
private final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
db.collection(collection).whereEqualTo(field, value).get();
```

**field** can be "created_on" and ***value*** can be today's date. There is also a provision to use other comparisons such as greater than or less than. The below link explains how to structure the queries:

[Perform simple and compound queries in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)

Please note that the query capabilities/number of times that you can use will depend on the plan you are with on Firebase. The free plan (Spark) allows you to retrieve only 3 results with compound queries. The paid plan (Blaze) has no limit.